# sort table drag and drop style and save new order

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sorting, html-table

I am using a jQuery plugin called jQuery Sortable (http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/). I am using the last example on the page, which is "Sort tables". I have made a table, which is sortable. The documentation isn't exhaustive, and my knowledge of jQuery is limited.

So far I have managed to sort the table drag and drop style. What I need to accomplish is to retrieve the id from each tr in their new order, store it in an array and post it to a server-side script.

```
<table class="table table-hover sorted_table">
<tbody>

<tr id="1">
<td>Something</td>
<td>Information</td>
<td>Column</td>
</tr>

<tr id="2">
<td>Something</td>
<td>Information</td>
<td>Column</td>
</tr>

<tr id="3">
<td>Something</td>
<td>Information</td>
<td>Column</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

<script>
// Sortable rows
$('.sorted_table').sortable({
containerSelector: 'table',
itemPath: '> tbody',
itemSelector: 'tr',
placeholder: '<tr class="placeholder"/>'
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var table = $('.sorted_table').sortable({
    containerSelector: 'table',
    itemPath: '> tbody',
    itemSelector: 'tr',
    placeholder: '<tr class="placeholder"/>',
    onDrop: function (item, container, _super) {
        var ids = table.find('tr').map(function() {
            return this.id;
        }).get();
    
        console.log(ids);
        _super(item, container);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/js/jquery-sortable.js"></script>

<table class="table table-hover sorted_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1">
            <td>Something1</td>
            <td>Information</td>
            <td>Column</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2">
            <td>Something2</td>
            <td>Information</td>
            <td>Column</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="3">
            <td>Something3</td>
            <td>Information</td>
            <td>Column</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```